# C++ compare 'string' to object from array

Tags: c++, string

I'm wondering why operator || doesn't work when I'm comparing 'input' with an element of array... AND(&&) works but that means my input has to be equal to every element of the table (or not - I don't get it). With || operator I always get result "0"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string days[7] = { "sr","czw","pt","sob","nd","pon","wt" };
    string day;
    cin >> day;

    if (day != (days[0]) || day != days[1] || day != days[2] || day != days[3] || day != days[4] || day != days[5] || day != days[6])
    {
        cout << "0";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "1";
    }
}
```

Comment: At least six of these conditions will always be true. true || false == true.

Comment: it does work but your logic is flawed. read about [de morgans law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: If you compare `day` to two (or more) different values, it will always be not equal to (at least) one of them, so the OR will always be true. What are you trying to achieve with your comparison? Do you want to output 0 if it's equal to one of the value in the array? Or 1?

Comment: @Simo there are seven and six of them must always be true, unless `day` can take on seven values at the same time.

Comment: You can shorten your condition by using [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) instead.

Comment: Do one of `a == cond1 || a == cond2...` or else `a != cond1 && a != cond2...`.

Comment: @tkausl Yes sorry, bad reading. I read `day = days[index]`

Comment: Just a quick C++11 example using a more friendly syntax, by introducing a helper function: https://www.ideone.com/Th1ZV5

Answer (score 1):

For displaying `1` the variable `day` should be 7 different values at the same time. Since that's is not possible you are seeing always `0`.

As a general rule(not strict) you should use `||` when you are doing a match (`==`) and not a mismatch(`!=`).

Comment: this is probably a comment and must be in the comments section

Comment: @NiVer https://i.imgur.com/Dt7kYu7.png
Hmm.. Wierd for me because of this || (it means or so I thought that it has to be like that: If(day!=monday or day!=tuesday etc.) so you say that it has to be like that, thanks ;)

Comment: @Pyrol exactly. Regardless of the value of day this statement will always be true. Also (day != days[3]) would be the 1 condition in that if () that would be false.

Comment: @drescherjm ammm... ok I get it, ty.

Comment: @drescherjm if you use `&&` it will always be false.

Comment: @Simo that is correct (it will be false) if there is a match.

Comment: True && True && True && True && True && True && False = False

Comment: I am agreeing with you.. I guess, I had a poor choice of words.

Answer (score 0):

Is not so clear what you want to achieve, because the logic behind the program is completly messed up.

if you code something like this:

```
if(day != (days[0]) || day != days[1] || day != days[2] || day != days[3] || day != days[4] || day != days[5] || day != days[6])
{
cout<<"0";
}
else
{
cout<<"1";
}
```

it will always execute the True branch of the IF, in this case `cout<<"0";`

Because `False || True = True` and six of your seven conditions will be always true.

You need to read and remember [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for future programs

---

So there are ***more than one solutions to fix*** this problem.

They might be:

**1.** Multiple If condition, one inside another:

```
if(day != (days[0]){
    if(day != (days[1]){
        if(day != (days[0]){
            //and so on ...
        }
        else{
            cout<<"1";
        }  
    }
    else{
        cout<<"1";
    }  
}
else{
    cout<<"1";
}
```

But this isn't clean, it's hard to read and I don't like it...

---

**2.** You can create a recursive function to check `day` value matching.

We can declare the function as a `void` because we don't need any returned value.

```
void dayCheckMatching(string days[], string day, int counter)
{
    if(day != (days[counter]){
        dayCheckMatching(days, day, counter)
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Day "<<day<<" matched at index: "<<counter;
        return;
    }
}
```

and than call it instead of the long `if condition` inside your main:

```
int main()
{

    string days[7] = {"sr","czw","pt","sob","nd","pon","wt"};
    string day;
    cin>>day;
    dayCheckMatching(days, day, 0)
    return 0;
}
```

---

***Remarks:***

As you can see in the void function example we used the `return;` statement in order to exit the function when `day` matched `days[index]` value. It is possible to use `return` to exit a function at any time, even if the function is `void`.